# Fisher z test to compare correlations in a time series

Tags: time-series, correlation, fisher-transform

I am running an analysis (in SAS, using proc corr fisher).
http://core.ecu.edu/psyc/wuenschk/docs30/CompareCorrCoeff.pdf

I basically want to know how different the correlations are on a daily basis for two groups with different variables.
I have several variables on a daily basis for a variety of stocks (I compute pooled, time series and cross sectional correlations over 5 years) which are classified into two groups. Basically it will end in an event study and I want to know if the correlations of two samples diverge in strengths before and after an event (t-5 to t+5).

Is the Fisher z test appropriate and how can I interpret figures?

Regards
M

Comment: I would think not if there is autocorrelation within the group.

Comment: Given also that nobs changes in event time, is there a non parametric test ?

Comment: I am not aware of one BUT other readers may be.